# Is there any other way of initialization of client library/package without using Google service account file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, service-accounts

I have a requirement for using multiple Google service account belongs to different owners in a multitenant architecture. Right now the problem is i have to keep the file path in an environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and client package use it implicitly.

How can i use multiple files or is there any way by i can initialize the package with id's & tokens like we do genrally with SDK's

```
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.SpeechClient() // can we initialize this client with explicit config
responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, self.get_requests())
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Google Client libraries support specifying which credentials you would like to use. Typically this is the `credentials` parameter.

Recommendations:

- Do not use environment variables for credentials in your use case. Specify the service account to use in your code. Your method uses ADC (Application Default Credentials). When you move or publish your code, you are dependant on the new environment.
- Do not manually specify "ids & tokens". A service account JSON key file is formatted to hold credentials.
- Create clients manually with all required parameters. Do not rely upon default mechanisms to set up your project/code.

[Client for Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/gapic/v1/api.html)

The following code is a simple example of using a service account with the Speech to Text API:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums

# Specify the required OAuth Scopes
# https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]

# Specify the desired Google Cloud Service Account JSON key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/config/service-account.json'

# Create credentials from the service account
cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create the Google Cloud Speech to Text Client
client = speech_v1.SpeechClient(credentials=cred)
```